# change visibility of all simple product

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, simple-product

**magento-1.9.2.4** I am using **nginx server** i would like to change  **catalog product visibility**.  only child products.

**FROM** "Catalog, Search"  **TO** "Not Visible Individually" So please how can i do it from database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mysql:** Magento save the relation between `configurable product and it child products` at `catalog_product_super_link` and save it product basic data  at `catalog_product_entity`  Table.

[image]

Write select query with `select type_id=simple` simple product and check `that product id exit` at `catalog_product_super_link` table  `product_id.` columns.

**For getting Simple products that are  associated with configurable product**

```
    SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity` where entity_id 
 in (SELECT product_id FROM `catalog_product_super_link`) and type_id='simple'
```

### Update Query:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int SET value = 1 WHERE
attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = "visibility")
AND
entity_id in (SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product_entity where entity_id   in (SELECT product_id FROM catalog_product_super_link) and 
type_id='simple');
```

Comment: i will check at night

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost doing things directly on the db is not often a good idea. I would recommend doing them either via the admin or via a script/import.

But if you would like to do this via the database the following should do it for you.

```
UPDATE
    catalog_product_entity_int
SET
    value = 1
WHERE
    attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = "visibility")
AND
    entity_id in (ADD YOUR PRODUCT IDS HERE);
```